# deployment - minor changes in web apps

Tags: svn, deployment, mercurial

I am using svn and giving a try with mercurial. I have a web-app of about 1K files. Consider these scenarios.

- I've deployed the web-app in server as **chekout**
- I've deployed the web-app in server as an **export**

Now I change a single line in one of the web pages in the deployed branch locally. Now I want the change to be updated on the deployed code (on server). If I want to transfer only the changed file to be transmitted to the server from local, what is the best possible way.

Think both checkout and export will transfer whole web-app to the server. Please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: To efficiently deploy with `export` you can use `rsync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercural `checkout` is an alias for `update` it doesn't move anything at all.  The commands that move things to your server are `push` and `pull` which move very space efficient binary representations of only what changed.  After pushing the changes to your server you'll need to `hg update` on the server, to make the working directory reflect the new repository changes, and that too alters only what changed.

The `hg export` command would be inappropriate here.  The `hg archive` command exports full snapshot archives, and moving those would mean moving everything.

Comment: is this the case with svn and other version control systems?

Comment: of course not.  They're all different in their command naming, and something like svn (centralized) is very different from git or Mercurial (decentralized)

Comment: ya. But update and checkout will be transferring only the **changes**, in svn, cvs, etc. Am I right?

Comment: Probably.  I'm thrilled to know very little about those systems. :)